# heatmap.js canvas not drawing when hovering content

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I'm building a website with a heatmap on it with heatmap.js by Patrick Wied. I manage to make it work and I'm now recording mouse move events as well as click events. Everything works very well except when I add some content on my website:

- The canvas for the heatmap is on the front layer and I can't select any text or click anything.
- I tried to put everything else than the canvas with a higher `z-index`, I can select and interact with my content but this time as the canvas is behind everything else, it does no record mouse events when I'm hovering some content.

I checked the [website](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) and [repo](https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js) of heatmap.js as it works perfectly, though I can't find any code or explanation on how to have a similar result. It looks like he isn't even playing with `z-index` to achieve this result.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

```js
var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
  container: document.querySelector('#heatmap'),
  radius: 30
});

document.querySelector('.wrapper').onmousemove = function(ev) {
  heatmapInstance.addData({
    x: ev.layerX,
    y: ev.layerY,
    value: 1
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper #heatmap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/heatmapjs@2.0.2/heatmap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="heatmap"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <button> Click me! </button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur animi ipsum fugit quibusdam excepturi quidem sequi vitae, dolor dignissimos ad rerum neque nam itaque illo perspiciatis eligendi, deserunt repellat in?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur animi ipsum fugit quibusdam excepturi quidem sequi vitae, dolor dignissimos ad rerum neque nam itaque illo perspiciatis eligendi, deserunt repellat in?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur animi ipsum fugit quibusdam excepturi quidem sequi vitae, dolor dignissimos ad rerum neque nam itaque illo perspiciatis eligendi, deserunt repellat in?</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you dot it, put the `content` above the `wrapper` by giving it higher `z-index` and add an event listener to `content` for the `mousemove`. when `mousemove` is fired on `content` it will simply froward that event to `wrapper` beneath it.

```js
var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
  container: document.querySelector('#heatmap'),
  radius: 30
});

document.querySelector('.wrapper').onmousemove = function(ev) {
  
  heatmapInstance.addData({
    x: ev.clientX,
    y: ev.clientY,
    value: 1
  });
};

document.querySelector('.content').onmousemove = function(ev) {
  let event = new ev.constructor( ev.type,ev)
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').dispatchEvent(event)
};
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper #heatmap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/heatmapjs@2.0.2/heatmap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="heatmap"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <button> Click me! </button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur animi ipsum fugit quibusdam excepturi quidem sequi vitae, dolor dignissimos ad rerum neque nam itaque illo perspiciatis eligendi, deserunt repellat in?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur animi ipsum fugit quibusdam excepturi quidem sequi vitae, dolor dignissimos ad rerum neque nam itaque illo perspiciatis eligendi, deserunt repellat in?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur animi ipsum fugit quibusdam excepturi quidem sequi vitae, dolor dignissimos ad rerum neque nam itaque illo perspiciatis eligendi, deserunt repellat in?</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox unfortunately :(

Comment: check the console what does it says?

Comment: Fails silently (no console output). I can select text, but the heatmap is 'stuck' in the top left corner and does not respond to any kind of mouse movement. I'm on macOS. Chrome seems to work fine.

Comment: @Throvn I fixed it was because of `layerX` and `layerY` which are not [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/layerX)

Comment: Absolutely amazing, I was banging my head on this one, thanks a lot!